# How to disable button until selections?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have two select elements and I want to disable submit button until both is has value.

I did some search and I found one nice code which works on old jQuery. The new version need update to work on jQuery 3.2.1 which my website currently uses.

I hope someone will provide me explanation why my code works perfectly on 1.5.2 and won't work on 3.2.1 version of jQuery.

Here is basic HTML of two selects, so I want to enable button only when both select has some value

```js
$('#btnProceed').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

function updateFormEnabled() {
  if (verifyAdSettings()) {
    $('#btnProceed').attr('disabled', '');
  } else {
    $('#btnProceed').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
}

function verifyAdSettings() {
  if ($('#buyoption').val() != '' && $('#selloption').val() != '') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false
  }
}

$('#buyoption').change(updateFormEnabled);

$('#selloption').change(updateFormEnabled);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" id="postForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 register-right">
      <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
          <h3 class="register-heading">
            <div class="row register-form">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <select class="form-control" name="buy" id="buyoption">
                    <option class="hidden" selected disabled value="">Please select what you want</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                  </select>
                </div><label for="buy"><b>YOU </b></label>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <select class="form-control" name="sell" id="selloption">
                    <option class="hidden" selected disabled value="">Please select what you to</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                </div><input type="submit" class="btnRegister" id="btnProceed" value="NEXT" /> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry i am new to this website, i will make a edit on the tags. Hope it will not push you guys from helping me

Comment: Please share HTML so we have  Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ikiK Just did it. I post two selects with html code. Now i only need explanation or edit of my jquery to work with version of 3.2.1

Comment: I've updated your snippet to combine the HTML and jQuery code in a single snippet. It is using 1.5.1 because 1.5.2 is unavailable from the the provider Stack Overflow uses. I don't believe there were any major changes between the two versions.

Comment: I strongly suggest you do some research into the changes that have occurred over the last two versions of jQuery and try to solve the problem yourself. You'll learn a lot and be better prepared for future endeavors.

Comment: @HereticMonkey , dude , I want script working in 3.2.1 .. I can not switch version on my website. so please help me with real problem not with making my post or problem in eye beautifull. but anyway thanks for edits.

Comment: @HereticMonkey , I don't have time, it must be done today...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a JSFiddle made from the given HTML and JS: https://jsfiddle.net/9e4yqthv/

There are minor issues with the HTML, please correct them (missing `</select>`, `</h3>`, etc).
As for the main issue, it seems that the line:

```
$('#btnProceed').attr('disabled', '');
```

Does not enable the button (the button still has the disabled property).
For that, change it to:

```
$('#btnProceed').removeAttr('disabled');
```

And the comparison under `verifyAdSettings` is incorrect - to check for a selection, check if the value is `null`, not `''`:

```
if ($('#buyoption').val() != null && $('#selloption').val() != null) {
```

NOTE: As mentioned by [Heretic Monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/heretic-monkey) in the comments, using `.prop()` is preferable to `.attr()` for enabling/disabling elements.

Usage:
`$('$btnProceed').prop('disabled', true);` to disable
`$('$btnProceed').prop('disabled', false);` to enable

Comment: You should be using `prop('disabled', false)` for enabling a button and `prop('disabled', true)` for disabling, as mentioned in [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/215552)